# Get value between two commas using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I want to edit a text file by using Excel data. The text file has the form:

```
Data1, Number1, Number2, ..., etc.
```

I want to get `Number1` and replace sum value(Number1+excel data). `Number2` is also the same flow.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sample reads in a text file, get every value between commas and sum it with cell A1's value `100`

**Input file** (C:\test.txt)

```
data1,1,2,3,4,5
data2,1,2,3,4,5
```

**Excel data** (Sheet 1)

```
[A1] = 100
```

#### Code

```
Sub ReadCommas()

    strPath = "C:\test.txt"
    Dim arVal() As String

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath)

    Do While Not objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine
        arVal = Split(strLine, ",")

        For i = 1 To UBound(arVal)
            arVal(i) = Val(arVal(i)) + Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
            Debug.Print arVal(i)
        Next i

    Loop
    objFile.Close

End Sub
```

**Output** (VBA editor » Immediate Window)

```
101
102
103
104
105
201
202
203
204
205
```

Answer (score 0):

I got value Number1 and Number2 as I wanted with the following Code:

**Input file (C:\intest.txt)**

```
Data1, 1, 2, ...etc
Data2, 3, 4, ...etc
...  
Data100, 200, 300, ...etc
```

**Excel data (Sheet 1)**

```
[A1] = 100, [B1] = 200
[A2] = 300, [B2] = 400
...  
[A100] = 2000, [B100] = 3000
```

**Code**

```
Sub ButtonClick()

    strPath = "C:\intest.txt"    

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = fso.OpenTextFile(strPath)

    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine        
        '※1 means Start Position of Num1
        intNum1Cnt = (InStr(※1, strLine, ",")) - ※1    'Count of Number1 of Data1:1
        dblNum1 = Mid(strLine , ※1, intNum1Cnt )        'Value of Number1 of Data1:1
        dblExcelNum1 = GetValue1()                       'Value of [A1]:100
        dblSumNum1 = dblNum1 + dblExcelNum1              'Sum:101
        'Replace dblSumNum1 to dblNum1 in OutputFile

        '※2 means Start Position of Num2
        ※2 = ※1 + intValue1Cnt + 1
        intNum2Cnt = InStr(※2, strLine, ",") - ※2       'Count of Number2 of Data1:1
        dblNum2 = Mid(strLine, ※2, intNum2Cnt)           'Value of Number2 of Data1:2
        dblExcelNum2 = GetValue2()                        'Value of [B1]:200            
        dblSumNum2 = dblNum2 + dblExcelNum2               'Sum:202
        'Replace dblSumNum2 to dblNum2 in OutputFile    
    Loop
    objFile.Close
End Sub
```

```
Function GetValue1() As Double

    For i = 1 To 100
        strCellValue1 = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
        GetValue1 = CDbl(strCellValue1)            
    Next i  
End Function
```

```
Function GetValue2() As Double

    For j = 1 To 100
        strCellValue2 = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 2).Value
        GetValue2 = CDbl(strCellValue2)            
    Next j  
End Function
```

**Output File (C:\outtest.txt)**

```
Data1, 101, 202, ...etc
Data2, 303, 404, ...etc
...  
Data100, 2200, 3300, ...etc
```